# Loading delay on my website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rendering, loading

I build my frontend with angularjs and i'm not satisfied with the performance. I used a lot of best practices for angularjs (such as ::) - but still - i have a strange delay and i don't know where it comes from. See this image:

[image]

Between 1000ms and 1600ms not much is happening. Has anyone experienced that with angularjs and any hints how to solve that?

My website: https://migranthire.com

---

Its not 100% right that nothing is happening - its loading templates for directives. But why is that taking 600ms? The templates are really really small.

Comment: You could load your templates as strings during compile step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be suffering from a few performance problems first thing I'd address are the TTFB since that can likely be solved through some server configuration adjustments.  Check the Timeline by selecting a network request and hitting the Timeline tab to see more details on what part of the communication it was stalled on (TTFB is what it appears to be from here, meaning the server is taking a long time to respond so not an angular problem but rather server config, or cloudfront).  Check resource usage on the server if possible or consider another service where you can or where the response times are better.

On the Angular side of things it's really only useful to Profile non minified code.  If you use the non-minified code locally you can go into the Profile tab and record a snapshot or use the main Timeline tab and record from initial load and then look at the bottom up view of script execution to see where it spends the most time.

To take angular out of the equation you can use curl and time.

```
time curl 'https://migranthire.com/pages/landingpage/landingpage.d9acd03520f27796.html' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'Accept: text/html' -H 'Referer: https://migranthire.com' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --compressed
```

Comment: Very insightful :) I will definitely check that with TTFB. I'm just wondering since i'm using AWS Cloudfront (all files are served from S3 then).
Might be a configuration problem. I can't check right now but i think the problem also exists on localhost (just a simple nodejs server)

Comment: It seems you were right with TTFB - my templates take 130ms each (TTFB). This is ridiculous. I'm using AWS CloudFront - what can i do there? (Edge Location is set to Europe - and i'am in Europe - so that shouldn't be the problem)

Comment: @FabianLurz sorry I haven't used CloudFront so I can't really speak to the merits or failures there, some Googling last night (CST) did come up with lots of complaints on Cloudfront response times.  On a somewhat tuned medium EC2 instance I typically get TTFB around 30ms +/-20ms and typically full response is loaded in around 50-70ms (angular itself being the outlier at 180ms total).  If you experience slowness locally through nginx or apache (both will be able to use the kernel to serve files directly from disk) then likely time to Profile the non-minified code to see what can be cut.

Comment: You may also want to try using Apache bench and/or siege to get more accurate results of response time under load

Comment: Ok - so the problem was basically, that CloudFront always had a "RefreshHit" - meaning, that the data had to be fetched from the S3 - which is slow. You have to Setup a TTL for objects in CloudFront - if its 0 your TTFB will be slow.

Comment: Good to know thanks for coming back with the details think you can answer your own question if you'd like to.